# Line breaks missing from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a quiz database in MySQL where both problem statement and solution (as correct_sol) are stored as text with utf8_general_ci collation. My problem is whenever I recall this information, the results don't have any line breaks. I am using the following code:

```
    $quiz_solution = $wpdb->get_results("query");

    foreach($quiz_solution as $item){
        $returnVal .= "Solution: $item->correct_sol <br>";
    }
    return $returnVal;
```

Not sure if getting the results as an Array is causing the problem.

Comment: You display the data probably in html, so you need to use `nl2br`

Comment: modify you concatenation to "Solution: ".$item->correct_sol." <br>";

Comment: How do you store the linebreaks? `<br>`'s? `\n`'s? `\r`'s?

Comment: @Hendriq yes nl2br works, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newlines are not rendered by the browser unless you use the `<br />` tag.

You can convert your newlines into break tags using [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

```
$returnVal .= "Solution: " . nl2br($item->correct_sol) . " <br>";
```

Comment: *..or unless you have any container element with the style `white-space: pre` on. (`such as <pre> elements by default`), **or** you output your content with `content-type: text/plain`*

Answer (score 1):

where your going to print this

use \n when you are returning as type/text output
use `<br />` when you are returning as type/html output